# What kind of clues scientist look for while hunting for new particles and how are their properties measured

Tags: particle-physics

While I was reading my physical chemistry book's notes on atomic structure I noticed that it mentioned several particles like pions, muons etc. While I was reading I got the question that what is the thing scientist look for while analyzing data for hints about new particle(s). One thing I thought of is that momentum conservation is not being followed but that is just one thing what kind of other clues can scientist use to track for evidences of a new particle

Also another thing that puzzled me was the concept of fractional charge. It stated that some particles (called quarks) had a fractional charge. How was this charge which was less than the supposed quantum of charge ascertained and must importantly ever measured

Comment: Two very different questions wrapped in there. For the second, early on we measured the charge on a proton and an electron, and found they are the same (except for sign). So, we called that charge '1'. It turns out the proton is not a fundamental particle, and consists of three quarks with charges a fraction of the proton. Well, we'd called the proton '1' already, but it turns out it was not a real 'quantum' of charge. We are stuck with it now. So it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Particle physicists look at two body scattering with large enough energy to produce a multitude of particles.

They check for new particles by taking invariant masses of the product particles , as for example [the Higgs](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/CMSPublic/PhysicsResultsHIG) was found in the LHC by the invariant mass plot of two hard photons.

Energy, momentum and quantum number conservation are used to check for the interactions and the type of particles. It is not a simple process and needs fitting of data. Look at this discovery of [omega minus event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_baryon).

[image: omega-]

To address the second part:

> It stated that some particles (called quarks) had a fractional charge. How was this charge which was less than the supposed quantum of charge ascertained and must importantly ever measured

The scattering experiments established the existence of a substrate in the nucleons, protons and neutrons. Also the model fitted the mesons with two quarks. At first it was called the [eightfold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_(physics)) and a mathematical model established that there were three particles within the nucleon. This finally led to the quark model.

> In addition to organizing the mesons and spin-1/2 baryons into an octet, the principles of the Eightfold Way also applied to the spin-3/2 baryons, forming a decuplet. However, one of the particles of this decuplet had never been previously observed. Gell-Mann called this particle the Ω−
>   and predicted in 1962 that it would have a strangeness −3, electric charge −1 and a mass near 1680 MeV/c2. In 1964, a particle closely matching these predictions was discovered[1](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/CMSPublic/PhysicsResultsHIG) by a particle accelerator group at Brookhaven. Gell-Mann received the 1969 Nobel Prize in Physics for his work on the theory of elementary particles.

So the fractional charges come from the symmetries observed and the consistency with an underlying quark content with group symmetry [SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1)](http://In%20addition%20to%20organizing%20the%20mesons%20and%20spin-1/2%20baryons%20into%20an%20octet,%20the%20principles%20of%20the%20Eightfold%20Way%20also%20applied%20to%20the%20spin-3/2%20baryons,%20forming%20a%20decuplet.%20However,%20one%20of%20the%20particles%20of%20this%20decuplet%20had%20never%20been%20previously%20observed.%20Gell-Mann%20called%20this%20particle%20the%20%CE%A9%E2%88%92%20and%20predicted%20in%201962%20that%20it%20would%20have%20a%20strangeness%20%E2%88%923,%20electric%20charge%20%E2%88%921%20and%20a%20mass%20near%201680%20MeV/c2.%20In%201964,%20a%20particle%20closely%20matching%20these%20predictions%20was%20discovered[1]%20by%20a%20particle%20accelerator%20group%20at%20Brookhaven.%20Gell-Mann%20received%20the%201969%20Nobel%20Prize%20in%20Physics%20for%20his%20work%20on%20the%20theory%20of%20elementary%20particles.) .